# Dependency injection in Guice

Tags: guice

```
public class N extends R {

    private final A a;
    private B b;

    @Inject
    N(@Assisted final A a, final B b) {
        a= a;
        b= b;
    }
}
```

My understanding of this is the parameter "a" I'll be providing and the Guice dependency injector will take care of injecting "b" correct ? Do I need to add any annotations for guice being able to inject "b", how do I inject "b" ?

Answer (score 3):

Guice is going to inject `B` based on how you configure it in your `Module`. You don't need to add anything else other than `@Inject` (which you already have). Here's a more complete example building on your class:

```java
public class GuiceExample {

  static class N {
    private final A a;
    private B b;

    @Inject
    N(@Assisted final A a, final B b) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
    }
  }

  static class A {}
  static class B {}

  static interface NFactory {
    public N create(A a);
  }

  static class Module extends AbstractModule {
    @Override 
    protected void configure() {
      install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().implement(A.class, A.class).build(NFactory.class));
      bind(B.class); // Or however you want B to be bound...
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    Injector i = Guice.createInjector(new Module());
    N n = i.getInstance(NFactory.class).create(new A());
  }

}
```

You should bind `B` in your `configure` method as you see fit. And you would inject `NFactory` into the class where you need to produce `N`s from `A`s.